# How can I suppress the "...this does not map back..." message when using SSH?

Tags: ssh, scripting, shell

I am writing a script that attaches to several of our machines via SSH to check some usage stats.

Each time I do:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/ourkeyfile.pem user@host
```

I get the typical message:

```
Address X.X.X.X maps to somedomain.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
```

Is there a commandline switch for ssh that lets me suppress this message from appearing in the output of my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what Danila suggested:

To suppress only the warnings and errors you would do this...

```
2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the script way is

```
2>&1 > /dev/null
```

The correct way is to fix ssh connection, host names.

---

Yeah, meaning need to fix known_hosts in .ssh folder.

Comment: oh right, of course, thanks. actually 2>/dev/null is what i want, because i don't want to suppress normal output. and also this is not a hosts problem. its a reverse ns lookup issue, not solvable from my end.

Comment: It is good to be a network and admin guy in the organization, as I do not have to wait for some network dude to update records for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the reverse DNS entry (PTR record) and possibly the forward entry (A and AAAA records) for the host in question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but its not wise to do that on  Amazon EC2 instances.